# RGB Pixels not rendering from image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm attempting to return the pixels of an image as RGB to printed to the screen. I'm loading the image with:

```
package graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture{
    public static Render floor = loadBitmap("/images/image2.png");
    public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName){
        try{
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResource(fileName)); 
            System.out.println("images loaded");
            int width = image.getWidth(); 
            int height = image.getHeight(); 
            Render result = new Render(width, height); 
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixel, 0, width); 
            return result; 
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Fatal error: imaging libraries missing or corrupt");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and rendering the pixels in a separate class with:

```
pixel[pixelPosition] = Texture.floor.pixel[((xPix & 7)) + ((yPix & 7 )) * 8];
```

where `pixel` is an `int[]` that has the parameters `[xPix + yPix *width]`. However, whenever I start up the program, the image loads(I know this because no errors are returned and I set up a print command to tell me if it loaded) but the pixels don't render. I thought maybe I just had to change `pixel` because it wasn't reading the image correctly, but then I found out that `pixel[pixelPosition] = ( ((xPix & 15) << xDisplacement) | ((yPix & 15)) << yDisplacement) & 0xffffff;` works just fine. So what's going wrong?

Comment: Do the source and target formats match? getPixel returns ARGB, which format do you need in Render? If this is for OpenGL, it is probably a different format. Maybe it is a transparency issue? Did you try to apply &0xffffff; to the data?

Comment: I'm not using openGL, and I just tried adding `& 0xffffff` to the end of `pixel[pixelPosition] = Texture.floor.pixel[((xPix & 7)) + ((yPix & 7 )) * 8];`, but that didn't work either. Supposedly to [this tutorial](http://brainycode.com/downloads/EPISODE_15.pdf), It should work. Is there something wrong with that tutorial?

Comment: Do the image sizes match? The fill code seems to assume a 8x8 image... Did you try printing the values in Texture.floor.pixel -- do they look as expected?

Comment: When I ran a print command like you suggested, at first it loaded the images perfectly, but then I got this message: `graphics.Render@3697a64Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64`. Fyi, `Render` is a separate class in the package `graphics`.

Comment: The indices range from 0..63 for an 8x8 image, so the exception when you access element 64 looks correct. Do the color values make sense? If you print them as hex values, you should easily be able to see whether the values for A, R, G and B match your expectations. Perhaps add the output (formatted as 8 rows of 8 values) to your question if you are not sure.